# JQuery undefined?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Getting a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined" (error) when running under IE8 (yes, it has to run under IE8). I reviewed (6) other posts under this title, none solved my problem. This *is* working under Chrome. This is a numeric spinner on 5 textbox controls. Error occurs on page load. Is this an IE8 issue? Thank you for your help.

```
    <link href="CSS/Styles.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/themes /ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="//btburnett.com/spinner/ui.spinner.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="scripts/ui.spinner.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//btburnett.com/spinner/ui.spinner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui.spinner.js" type="text/javascript">        
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery().ready(function($) {
            $('#txtClockInEarlyGraceMinutes').spinner({ min: 0, max: 120, step:1 });
            $('#txtClockInLateGraceMinutes').spinner({ min: 7, max: 30, step:1 });
            $('#txtClockOutEarlyGraceMinutes').spinner({ min: 7, max: 30, step:1 });
            $('#txtClockOutLateGraceMinutes').spinner({ min: 7, max: 120, step:1 });
            $('#txtMaxWorkHours').spinner({ min: '<%=Session("MaxWorkHours_MIN") %>', max: '<%=Session("MaxWorkHours_MAX") %>' });
            //$('#TextBox11').spinner({ min: 0, max: 10 });         
            //$('#TextBox17').spinner({ min: 0, max: 240, step:5 });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: BTW, when I view source in Chrome, I can confirm links to everything...

Comment: I think your `ready` function may be the problem, try changing it to `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... }`

Comment: nah, that's not a problem. it's poor practice, but not a problem.

Comment: I've just never seen it constructed like that, it seems like a mashup of the two most common styles.

Comment: I kinda suspect it to be a network related issue, maybe even ssl if https is being used.

Comment: yes, https is being used. Suggestions?

Comment: navigate directly to one of the assets via https, and accept the certificate. Or serve them locally.

Comment: I downloaded all the .js and .css source and referenced them locally without change. I posted the url's to avoid questions regarding the files themselves. So, I think this takes the ssl out of the loop.

Comment: indeed it does. It rules out the majority of possible causes actually.

Comment: I have not used a Spinner before, just found this solution on the web... is there a way to BETTER express the function that is being called? Would something (wrong) on the page prevent jquery from loading? As mentioned, works fine under Chrome and View Source in IE looks nicely formatted as well... thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery version > 2.0 
less then 2.0 version it's mostly show Undefined problem

Comment: jQuery 2.0 and above do not support IE8, which the OP he has to support.

Comment: v1.8.3 was the last version to support $.browser.msie which is also required (unless I modify the code).